VisualStudio debugger using older version of source files
I just upgraded to the latest version of Visual Studio - 17.10.0 Preview 3.0
And the debugger is now showing me source files from several days ago in the debugger. These older version of the files don't exist anywhere on my system but it somehow is finding them somewhere and using them in the debugger.
These resurrected files are then placed in folders under C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\SourceServer
What's going on here? And how do I stop this?
Update: I found the cause! When I run the debugger, when I hit an issue, I write a note right there in the code. When I'm done debugging I then go address the items I wrote. This happens after I write my first note.
Still no idea why Visual Studio has suddenly decided to act this way when the source changes. And no idea where it finds the out of date source file (generally the state of the source from several days ago). But that's the cause.
Still have the question - how do I fix it?

To the individual who voted to close the question - can you provide guidance on how it could be worded better? TIA

Did you raise it using VS feedback? This looks more like a bug and so Microsoft devs might be better positioned to help. That being said, they'll probably need a repro. Exactly like us here. I just had a bug fixed in 17.10P3 in this area so it's possible there are more.

Try turning off the "Source Link" function: Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General, find the "Enable Source Link support" option and uncheck it.

I've done everything you suggested except "Require source files to exactly match..." several times - no luck. I can't require a match because as soon as I type in a source file it then will stop the session and recompile. I think you're right that it's pulling the source file from GitHub. But why it does that because I've edited a local file - that's the key question. TIA

This may be due to a feature of Visual Studio called "Source Link", which downloads source files from source code servers such as GitHub during debugging. When editing a source file locally, Visual Studio may detect changes to the source file and try to get the latest version from GitHub.
Try turning off the "Source Link" function:
Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General, find the "Enable Source Link support" option and uncheck it.

That was it. Please change your answer to unchecking "Enable Source Link support" and I'll be happy to select your answer. thanks

I'm glad to know that this method is useful to you. I will change the answer to unchecking "Enable Source Link support" according to your wishes.
